# Call a function from solidity contract Typescript

Tags: solidity, react, typescript

I have to call a function from the contract i've made from react typescript.
Can anyone help me to do this ??

**`This is my contract:`**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.10;
contract HelloWorld {

   string public message;

   constructor(string memory initMessage) public {
      message = initMessage;
   }

   function update(string memory newMessage) public {
      message = newMessage;
      }
}
```

Comment: You can use [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/).

Comment: Well I am a very beginner to react. Can you provide me some sample code??

Comment: See my project [create-eth-app](https://github.com/paulrberg/foundry-template). Not TypeScript but you should be able to quickly adapt it.

Comment: Also see [scaffold-eth](https://github.com/scaffold-eth/scaffold-eth).

Comment: Can i use use [useDApp's useCall function ??](https://usedapp-docs.netlify.app/docs/api%20reference/hooks/#usecall)